# Getting started with macvim, how to manage a project?

Tags: macvim

I have started out with macvim and now fairly comfortable with the navigation (on a single file) and now I need to write a whole project (say rails) using mvim.

In textmate, you have `mate project_dir` which opens the project in a side drawer, so my question is:

1. Is there a similar feature in mvim?
2. How can a complete project managed in traditionally in macvim?

Links to some write-ups are welcomed.

Comment: try http://vimcasts.org/ for more general information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus). Made it really easy for me to switch from TextMate.

Answer (score 10):

As @changelog pointed out, the absolute best way to get MacVim to behave like Textmate is to use [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus). Janus packages up a bunch of popular plugins and provides an easy way to keep those pluggins up-to-date via a rakefile. Janus also includes NERDTree (mentioned by @zengr) along with a variety of other tools that make it really easy to manage a big project.

In order to launch mvim the way that you launch textmate with `mate project_dir`, an mvim script is included in the MacVim download. You just need to put it in your path (I keep mine in `/usr/local/bin/mvim`). Using this script you can do the exact same thing:

`mvim project_dir` - to open a specific directory in MacVim

`mvim .` or just `mvim` - to open your current directory in MacVim

Answer (score 6):

After trying out many plugins, [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) was the best match. [Read more](http://sterlingcobb.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/macvim-with-ruby-on-rails/)

[image]

#### Install Details

https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=23731

> Unzip the archive into your `~/.vim` directory. That should put
> NERD_tree.vim in `~/.vim/plugin` and NERD_tree.txt in `~/.vim/doc`.

Answer (score 2):

[PROJECT](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) is really awesome.
You can easily add folders to your project (single ones, or recursively), specify filters, etc.

It's really worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try `:help mksession`.

Load all your 'project' files (either interactively or using the command line `vim file1 file2 ...`.) Running `:mksession xxx` writes a vim script to restore the environment and load all currently loaded files.

Next time just `:source xxx` to reload your environment (or run `vim -s xxx` to execute the file on startup).

Note: For navigating *source* files (as opposed to data files), `ctags` is, in my opinion, a better option. Create a ctags database (ctags works for Ruby scripts too!) and navigate in your code tree using `:tag myfunc`. No need to preload any file.

Comment: is that the only way to manage multiple files? VIM does not have a plugin for that?

Comment: @zengr: What is it that you are missing in terms of project management? I do use the bufferexplorer plugin for switching buffers (once they are loaded). Others use the fuzzyfinder plugin.

Comment: @zengr: OK. Seems like there's a "project" plugin as well. Take a look at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69